# In Vim, / (search in normal mode) and search function returns different results

Tags: regex, vim

I have a simple text file.

```
blah.
[{}]
[{foo}]
```

My cursor is at the beginning of the file. I want to search for (possibly empty) strings embraced with [{}].

So the regex pattern is `"\[{.*}\]"`,right?

When I use the normal search

```
/\[{.*}\]
```

The cursor is relocated at the second line, good!

But if I use the `search` function

```
:echo search("\[{.*}\]")
```

The cursor goes to the final `.` of the first line and the result of `echo` is 1, meaning the first match is in line 1.

Why and how can I get the same result as the normal search using a function?

Thanks.

Comment: Can't reproduce: Ubuntu 12.04 both methods work the same in vim.

Comment: @kestasx That's interesting. My Vim is version 7.4.537 and I am running arch linux. Maybe this is a new bug?

Comment: My version 7.3.429. It it is realy different behaviour (You can reproduce it), Arch or Vim forum/bugtracker may be more appropriate place to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(I copy below my answer to the vim_use mailing list:)

You are using double quotes in the first search argument. The backslash
in the double quote has a special meaning and basically just means to
use the character after it. In your case the search function sees at it
first argument the pattern `[{.*}]` which happens to match in the last
column of line 1.

The solution is, to either use single quotes or escape the character
twice, if you use double quote.

This is explained at the help at :h expr-quote